# Android read from multiple text files and show in table view

Tags: android, android-activity, textview, tableview

I want some help with putting data from multiple text files into one table shown on an activity.

The text file has a value on each line.

I want these strings to be shown on one column, in a table, where each column shows another text files data of similar format.

I want something like this to be shown:

[image: table]

The code im currently using shows one text file in a textview, how can i manipulate the code to make what i need possible?

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stats);

        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        String path = sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/SO/";  
        File file = new File(path + "cheststats.txt");

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
                text.append('\n');
            }
            br.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a good question, because all trivial information that you need for doing this are on [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/index.html). But anyway, I hope following steps help you:

1) Create `stats.xml` layout for stats table:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableStats"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Stats"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/textView4" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text File 1 Data"
            android:id="@+id/textView1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text File 2 Data"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text File 3 Data"
            android:id="@+id/textView3" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

2) Create `stats_row.xml` layout for stats table rows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|end" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|end" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|end" />
</TableRow>
```

3) Next, create function for reading file:

```
    private List<String> readFileData(String filePath) {
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            BufferedReader fileBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filePath)));
            String value;
            while ((value = fileBufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                values.add(value);
            }
            fileBufferedReader.close();
        } catch (IOException ignore) {
        }

        return values;
    }
```

4) Create function for filling stats row view:

```
    private void fillView(View view, String dataset1Value, String dataset2Value, String dataset3Value) {
        TextView textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView textView3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        textView1.setText(dataset1Value);
        textView2.setText(dataset2Value);
        textView3.setText(dataset3Value);
    }
```

5) Finally your `onCreate` function should be like this:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stats);

        TableLayout tableStats = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableStats);

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/SO/";

        List<String> data1 = readFileData(path + "file1.txt");
        List<String> data2 = readFileData(path + "file2.txt");
        List<String> data3 = readFileData(path + "file3.txt");

        int maxDataSetSize = Math.max(data1.size(), Math.max(data2.size(), data3.size()));

        for (int i = 0; i < maxDataSetSize; i++) {
            String dataset1Value = data1.size() > i ? data1.get(i) : null;
            String dataset2Value = data2.size() > i ? data2.get(i) : null;
            String dataset3Value = data3.size() > i ? data3.get(i) : null;

            View statsRowview = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.stats_row, null);

            fillView(statsRowview, dataset1Value, dataset2Value, dataset3Value);

            tableStats.addView(statsRowview);
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure that it will work at the first attempt. I have not tested.

Comment: Thanks ill play around with it and give it a go.

Comment: Yep works like it should, thanks a lot, only problem is that it isnt formatted properly, it isnt coming under the headings, its coming in the space, eg 
Text file 1 data        text file 2 data - the data is coming in the gaps instead of under the heading. ill play around with it

Comment: I guess you need to change `gravity` attr in `textView1`, `textView2`, `textView3`

Comment: Yep have done that but one more problem. The text file has values lets say 1 2 3 4 but the activity is only showing 1 2 3, its not showing the final value. However when its just 1 2 its showing all of it. Dont know whats up seems a bit odd to me

Comment: Yes, it's weird. May be you don't have enough space on screen device? Can you provide your text files content?

Comment: Im sure theres enough space on the screen as its only covering top half of the screen at the moment, i will upload the text file somewhere and post link here

Comment: Heres the text file: http://ul.to/nrfagg4e
so they all show except the last value. It shows after ive added another value but again the last value does not show.

Comment: Why did you add a blank line between values?

Comment: my text editor shows me blank lines between values, but I guess it's not about your problem. Did you edit my code? can you provide it for me?

Comment: Check main post ive put it there, If you can help get this sorted i will be greatly happy

Comment: Ok, I've got it. Upload all your files for me I'll try to check it on my device

Comment: Haha okay ill upload my whole app somewhere

Comment: I mean text files with stats, not all your project.

Comment: Okay let me upload all 3.

Comment: pls, upload to other file hosting, uploaded.net has limit by time, I can't download your archive

Comment: Stupid mistake... just change `for (int i = 0; i < maxDataSetSize - 1; i++) {` to `for (int i = 0; i < maxDataSetSize; i++) {`

Comment: Had a feeling it was this but wasnt sure xD

Comment: Works great now, cheers :D Ill keep you updated if theres any other trouble but doubt it thanks!

Comment: One last thing is it possible to put this in a slide view so i have 3 pages with the same table but different information inside. So the basic layout is same but is for different days. So one page for day 1, day 2, day 3 - where all have the same table, but populated with different text files. Just saves me making a button for each day if its possible to slide between them. Thanks!

Comment: Yes it's possible, but I have no enough time for do it for you. I believe you cope with this yourself. Just read about  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: Am wondering if its possible to colour the cells based on another text file, so you have "file1.txt" which fills the columns, and then ""file1colour.txt" for that column, so if it is green red green in that text file the first row will appear green, then red, then green again.

Comment: Yes, you can do it. Just find color's codes for example here: http://html-color-codes.info/. And fill your file, lets say fist row is `#01DF01`, second is `#FF0000` and so on. Next read that file like as few others and apply your colors to TextView background like this: `textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colorLine));`, where `colorLine` is row from `file1color.txt` and `textView` is one of your `TextView`s (`textView1`, `textView2`, `textView3`). I hope it helps you. Good luck.

Comment: Ive managed to get the colors showing, but its looking like this http://puu.sh/fMfrt/03a298d2ee.png

Instead of http://puu.sh/fMfxx/bb5389687f.png

Ive posted my code in the top

Comment: I'll try to help you tomorrow

Comment: Cheers mate appreciate everything youve done for me!